# SAXParseException; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name '...' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, xerces

I'm trying to do schema validation, currently using a `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory`. Unfortunately When I call the `newSchema(Source schema)` function, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/C42056/Documents/workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/cec-sample-ws-integration-2-war/target/classes/WEB-INF/schemas/xsd/individual/PrivateComponentTypes_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 88; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'utility:ObjectStatusDateType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sei.ec.xml.validation.SimpleXmlValidator.loadSchema(SimpleXmlValidator.java:70)
at com.sei.ec.xml.validation.SimpleXmlValidator.<init>(SimpleXmlValidator.java:83)
... 75 more
```

The `utility:ObjectStatusDateType` element is used in the .xsd file which I am passing into the `newSchema(Source schema)` function. I am importing the `ObjectStatusDateType` from another .xsd file- for which I have tripple checked the file path.  The `utility` namespace is also declared properly.

Here's a snippet of the schema I am passing into the function (LocateCoverageIndexesByIdentifier_3_0.xsd):

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sei.com/utility/1/" schemaLocation="../../utility/InvocationOutcome_1_0.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sei.com/utility/1/" schemaLocation="../../utility/ObjectHistory_1_0.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sei.com/individual/component/4/" schemaLocation="../PrivateComponentTypes_4_0.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.sei.com/individual/shared/5/" schemaLocation="../IndividualTypes_5_0.xsd"/>
.
. <!-- Some more stuff -->
.
<xs:element name="coveragePeriod" 
            type="utility:ObjectStatusDateType" 
            minOccurs="0"/>
```

And this is from ObjectHistory_1_0.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:tns="http://www.sei.com/utility/1/" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.sei.com/utility/1/" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           version="1.0">
.
. <!-- Some more stuff -->
.
  <xs:complexType name="ObjectStatusDateType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="effectiveDate" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element name="cancelDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And lastly, the bean

```
<bean id="locateClaimValidator" 
      class="com.sei.ec.xml.validation.SimpleXmlValidator">
  <constructor-arg>
    <value>classpath:WEB-INF/schemas/xsd/individual/ci/LocateCoverageIndexesByIdentifier_3_0.xsd
    </value>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Has anybody encountered this type of issue before?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve it? If so then what worked out for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this issue before. Everything validated in Eclipse, but broke when running. Do any of your schemas import more than one schema into the same namespace?

Something like this will not work, but will be validated by Eclipse:

```
<import namespace="http://www.whatever.gov" location="../wherever" />
<import namespace="http://www.whatever.gov" location="../folder/superawesomeschema.xsd" />
```

Comment: This solved it.  Sorry, I should have initially included more of the file in my first code tag (made that edit).  I was including two xsd files under the http://www.sei.com/utility/1/ namespace, one of which being the ObjectHistory_1_0.xsd.  It's always the stupid stuff...

Comment: sorry it wont work to validate when another namespace is included ?

Comment: Replace the attribute "location" with "schemaLocation" (see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_import.asp)

Answer (score 6):

Lots of people have encountered this type of issue before.  It comes up whenever your validator is, for whatever reason, not loading the schema documents you want it to load (and think it's loading).

To confirm the diagnosis:  try introducing an error -- say, a well-formedness error -- into ObjectHistory_1_0.xsd, and see if the system complains.

Comment: You were right.. If I change something about ObjectHistory_1_0.xsd, the factory doesn't pick up the issue

Answer (score 5):

Using Xerces this can solved by setting the feature
`http://apache.org/xml/features/honour-all-schemaLocations` to true.

The feature `http://apache.org/xml/features/honour-all-schemaLocations` is only available
from Xerces 2.7.0. Current releases of Java 5.0 and 6.0 have a Xerces 2.6.2
built-in. Hence one has to use a newer Xerces library in order for this to work,
ie. copying `xml-apis.jar` and `xercesImpl.jar` to `<jdk-home>/jre/lib/endorsed` and
creating a `jaxp.properties` file in `<jdk-home>/jre` containing the line

```
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory\:http\://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when executing the maven plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin.
After explicitly mentionning the xsd file to parse, it worked like a charm:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>xjc</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <schemaFiles>MySchema.xsd</schemaFiles>
     <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This helps me also - explicitly point to exactly one `xsd` file (there are several `xsd` files in the same directory).